# Call another php from another domain and get the result

Tags: php, wordpress, post

I'm trying to call a php from another php passing data to it and getting the return value. The two php's are on different domains.

First php:

```
    $url = 'http://myweb.com/custom-php/createCat.php';
    $data = array('name' => $name);

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    echo $result;
```

Second php (It's on a Wordpress site):

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    require('../wp-load.php');

    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
    echo $name;
    if(isset($name))
    {
        echo wp_create_category($name,0);
    }
    else
    {
        echo false;
    }
```

I get the following error:

file_get_contents(http://myweb.com/custom-php/createCat.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

But if i access it via http://myweb.com/custom-php/createCat.php?name=test it works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request error could be because the ***allow_url_fopen*** PHP.ini directive is set **off** in the remote URL.

So an alternative may be using CURL:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://myweb.com/custom-php/createCat.php';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$result= curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

**Answer to the comment '*how can i send the data i need(a variable with some text)*':**

Use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=test&var=" . urlencode($someText));
```

Comment: Hi, the allow_url_fopen directive is set to On.

Using CURL, how can i send the data i need(a variable with some text)?.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad to know it ;)

Answer (score 0):

When you visit the url you make a get request.
You should do the same in your php:

```
$url = 'http://myweb.com/custom-php/createCat.php';
$data = array('name' => $name);

$result = file_get_contents($url . '?' . http_build_query($data));

echo $result;
```

Also, you need to check if the `$_REQUEST` key is set before using it:

```
//this header is only required for ajax..
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
require('../wp-load.php');

if(isset($_REQUEST['name'];))
{
    echo wp_create_category($_REQUEST['name'],0);
}
else
{
    echo false;
}
```

Comment: Hi, doing that gets me the following error:

<b>Warning</b>:  file_get_contents(http://myweb.com/custom-php/createCat.php?name=catTest): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
 in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\general\php\insertCategory.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />

Where line 29 is the file_get_contents line, but clicking on the link that the error provides works.